# Is there an equivalent concept in engineering to CS's "search space reduction"?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am looking to learn more about how engineers efficiently search for solutions to problems, particularly mechanical engineers.

Computer scientists sometimes speak of "search space reduction" when they are trying to make an algorithm more tractable. For example, if a search space is small, trial-and-error or "brute force" may be a very efficient method to implement because it is easy to execute.

Do engineers have a similar concept?

Comment: Any method used will depend on the problem that is being solved. Do you have a problem in mind? If not, the question is too broad.

Comment: Yes, but it's too complicated to explain at this point in time. It's BME related and I'm not sure I'm in a position to give specifics off hand.

Comment: read "The Engineering Method" by Taylor (available online, a few hours at most), it goes into the thinking process of engineers quite well IMO. What most engineers do is to look for a solution that has worked in a case similar to the one they face now. Experience is very relevant because of that. Also drink beer with working engieers and get them to talk about their style of problem solving.

Comment: The method of engineering I was taught was (1) - Formally define the problem, (2) - Look if it or a similar problem was already solved, (3) - Modify the result of (2) to fit the problem at hand. If (2) doesn't turn up anything, then you're into a brainstorming/concept generation state, at which point you should be receptive to *all* ideas. (Un)Fortunately you can't typically make open-ended projects "tractable" - solving them is all the fun!

Comment: It sure is a waste of energy for all of us when a question gets removed after it is answered. I feel it was a legitimate question but can not see how to properly modify it. Would one of the members putting it on hold kindly make some edits or give some suggestions?

Comment: @ericnutsch I did. And was shot down.

Answer (score 2):

I think the analogy does not fit, because of a confusion between levels of abstraction.

Imagine you need to attach a plastic bar and an aluminium rod. Solving this engineering problem involves deciding whether to use a mechanical fastener, or a joint, or an adhesive, or whatever else; or experimenting with a few different methods until you find something that works. This is a *design* level issue. Influencing factors might be things like:

- What loads that will be applied?
- Is it visible and does it need to look neat?
- What environmental conditions will it be subject to? (underwater or in air, temperatures, pressures, etc.).
- What wear will it take and how long does it need to last?

Now imagine you need to find all 5-digit integer palindromes that are a multiple of an input integer `<n>`. Solving this computer science problem involves choosing a programming language/platform, selecting an algorithm, and writing some code; or experimenting with a few different methods until you find something that works. This is also a *design* level issue. Influencing factors might be things like:

- How often will be it called and how fast does it need to perform?
- Is this a sub-routine of a larger program or a stand-alone program?
- How will it be called? (Function, command line, HTTP request, etc.)
- What sort of output should it produce - who are the consumers?

Reducing the search space in computer science is at a different level of abstraction to the above design tasks. Say for example you write the program in Python and you run it as a stand-alone program from the command line so that a human can view the output. A crude implementation might be sufficient:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def isPalindrome(n):
    return str(n) == str(n)[::-1]

def isMultiple(n, d):
    return (n % d) == 0

for i in xrange(10000,99999+1):
    if isMultiple(i, 17) and isPalindrome(i):
        print i;
```

This was very quick to write, and there is no need to optimise or improve it because doing so would be a waste of time considering how it is intended to be used. The analogous solution in the engineering problem is to use a glue-gun or some tape because the plastic bar is only there to stop the sliding aluminium rod form moving around during transit.

Now, what if those design requirements changed?

If the palindrome generator needs to be called many times per second from an app with a large user-base over an HTTP connection then I may consider a different approach re. platform, language, interface, etc. but I would also certainly consider reducing the search space of the algorithm. Instead of a loop over all integers with two tests, I'd only consider multiples of `<n>` to start with by starting at the first one and adding `n` each time. This is an optimisation or *performance* level issue.

Similarly, if the plastic bar had to attach to the aluminium rod in order to prevent a user-facing keypad panel from deflecting during general use over a 5 year lifetime then I may consider a different connection type, such as a simple shaped joint with adhesive, and I would certainly consider the equivalent *performance* level issue of what adhesive to use. I would look up adhesive strengths for both material types and effective operating conditions depending on what environment it would be used in.

So you see, the analogy doesn't really work. Reducing the search space is highly specific to both the task at hand and how it's implemented. It's about trivial rejection, to eliminate (or not consider in the first place) unsuitable candidates. CS: Reduce the total number of tests that need to be performed; EN: Eliminate unsuitable adhesives. Both highly specific optimisations of the task at hand. What you're talking about is a general purpose way to reduce the "search space" of possible *design* solutions. Which doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

"Trial and error" and "brute force" are terms I frequently use in engineering.

Thomas Edison is famous for his "brute force" invention of a long life incandescent light bulb. Other incandescent light bulbs had been created before him, but burnt out quickly. He was reasonably certain a long lasting bulb could be created if he had the right filament material; so his company proceeded to test every combination.

However most of the time engineers use physics and industry knowledge to more efficiently solve problems. The Hoover Dam was engineered based on physical principles and past experimentation so that it only needed built one time.